# Convert man page nroff overstrike text into highlight regions

Tags: pager

#### Problem

I want to view `man`-pages in colour, **preserving `nroff`'s bold and italic directives**.

How would I edit a buffer's text and setup highlight regions:

- `manpage_bold`: For all instances of `X` `<backspace>` `X`:

  - Conceal / remove the final 2 characters, leaving only the first.
- `manpage_italic`: For all instances of `_` `<backspace>` `X`:

  - Conceal / remove the leading two characters, leaving only the last.

Where `X` is any character other than backspace.

---

#### Background

I have [`less` configured to display manual pages in colour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/329092/143394):

[image: Coloured man page example]

This is achieved by telling `less` to replace *overstrikes* that `groff`/`nroff` produces to indicate bold / italics with [ANSI SGR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics) colour codes.

I want `vim` to be able to do the analogous thing: view man pages with the original bold / italics by removing the overstrikes and setting up highlight regions.

#### Overstriking

What's an overstrike I hear you ask? **takes deep breath**

Unix is a venerable old operating system, dating from the times when teletypes hammered inked ribbon, imprint characters on paper.

**Bold** characters were printed by printing the character, backspacing, then printing the same character again - twice as much ink was impressed upon the paper.

*Italic* characters are indicated by printing an underscore (`_`), backspace and then the character to be rendered. [(source)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274795/143394)

Over 40 years later, `man` still uses `nroff` to generate the text that is displayed from the `troff` man page source file... and `nroff` still uses overstriking to indicate boldface / italics.

---

#### Non-solutions

[neoman](https://github.com/nhooyr/neoman.vim) and [vim-man-pager](https://github.com/lambdalisue/vim-manpager) only colour by regular expression- they remove the `nroff` bold / italic directives which are useful in warnings, etc.

When using `GROFF_SGR=1` to produce ANSI SGR codes rather than overstrikes,
[AnsiEsc](https://github.com/powerman/vim-plugin-AnsiEsc) is needed to display the output, and this doesn't work with `set ft=man` syntax highlighting.

Comment: you might want to check my plugin [Colorizer](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer/) (at least I just added highlighting for those nroff sequences mentioned here

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't strip the control characters - I can't use Ctrl-K to jump to the referenced man page. Also, it's noticeably slower than my `less` setup.

Comment: of course it doesn't. It is supposed to hide them using concealing. and yes concealing is known to be slow, especially with long documents and many ansi control characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear from your question+comments if you want to remove the original control sequences bofore applying syntax highlighting in vim. Here are some solutions/alternatives.

**From inside the editor:**

[Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) ships with a `:Man` command that displays man pages and does all the magic for you. (This one removes the original control characters).

For plain vim you might use a plugin like [vim-man](https://github.com/vim-utils/vim-man) to achive the same.

**From the command line:**

If you want to use vim or neovim as a pager from the command line you can use [vimpager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager) or [nvimpager](https://github.com/lucc/nvimpager).  Both can handle and highlight man pages by default (nvimpager relies on the code from neovim for that).  Vimpager works with vim and neovim, nvimpager is faster but only for neovim.

(Disclosure: I am the developer of [nvimpager](https://github.com/lucc/nvimpager) and have also helped in development with [vimpager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager).)

**DIY:**

You can look up the implementation in [Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) or [vim-man](https://github.com/vim-utils/vim-man) to see how they do it and adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now using `neovim` and `:Man` seems to do the trick, however I'd like to be able to change the underline to a different colour as it looks ugly to my eyes. How do I find out the `SyntaxRegion`name of both bold and underline?

Comment: You can use the [`synID()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#synID()) and `synIDattr()` functions to find the syntax group names and other attributes of any line and char in the file.